# Dynamic real-time system problem

Tags: dynamical-systems, laplace-transform, systems-theory

I am struggling with a systems theory problem, the task is as follows:

u(t) -> H(s) -> y(t)

H(s) being the transfer function

$$
H(s) =  H(s) = \frac{s+1}{s(s+2)^{2}}
$$

$$
u(t) =  e^{-5t}
$$

So using Laplace transformation i get

$$
u(s) = \frac{1}{s+5}
$$
From here I try to calculate Y(s)
$$
Y(s) = \frac{1}{s+5} * \frac{s+1}{s(s+2)^{2}}
$$
And this is were I am stuck, I have used partial fraction decompostion like so:
$$
Y(s) = \frac{1}{s+5} * \frac{s+1}{s(s+2)^{2}} = \frac{k_{1}}{s} + \frac{k_{2}}{s+2} + \frac{k_{3}}{(s+2)^{2}} + \frac{k_{4}}{s+5}
$$
However that has not worked, so could anyone please help me out? Give some guidance on how to move forward and get the y(t).

Thank You!

Comment: You should have the Laplace transform of $u$ as $U(s) = \frac1{s+5}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$Y(s) = \left(\frac1{5+s}\right)\left(\frac{1+s}{s(2+s)^2}\right) = \frac{1+s}{s(2+s)^2(5+s)}. $$
The partial fraction decomposition is of the form
$$\frac{1+s}{s(2+s)^2(5+s)} = \frac As + \frac B{2+s} + \frac C{(2+s)^2} + \frac D{5+s}. $$
This implies
$$A(2+s)^2(5+s) + B(s(2+s)(5+s)) + C(s(5+s)) + D(s(2+s)^2) = 1+s $$
for all $s$. Taking $s=0$ yields
$$20A=1\implies A=\frac1{20}, $$
taking $s=-2$ yields
$$-6C = -1\implies C=\frac16, $$
taking $s=-5$ yields
$$-45D = -4 \implies D = \frac4{45}, $$
and finally, taking $s=-1$ yields
$$4A - 4B - 4C  -D = 0\implies B = \frac1{4}\left(\frac4{20}-\frac46-\frac4{45}\right)=-\frac5{36}. $$
It follows that
$$Y(s) = \frac{1}{20 s}-\frac{5}{36 (s+2)}+\frac{1}{6 (s+2)^2}+\frac{4}{45 (s+5)} ,$$
and so
$$y(t) = \mathcal L^{-1}\{Y(s)\}=\frac1{20}e^{-t} -\frac5{36}e^{-2t} + \frac16 te^{-2t} +\frac4{45}e^{-5t}. $$